# Is dev.meta.stackoverflow.com gone?

Tags: discussion, support, meta

Sorry If I am posting in wrong place, but when I try to login to dev.meta.stackoverflow.com today, I got password protected page and looks like previous password is not valid anymore.

Comment: I just realized this too. That banner is really hard to spot :(

Comment: i really miss dev.meta.stackoverflow.com :)!But welcome stackapps.com!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you look on that password page, it says:

> Thank you for participating in the
>   private API beta! We're now starting
>   the public beta - you can find more
>   information on http://stackapps.com.

The dev.meta.stackoverflow.com site is no longer active. This is the new location for API related subjects.

You should have goten an email notifying you of this.

Comment: Ah, my company recently banned https, cannot check my gmail at the moment. Thank you Chacha.

Comment: I see your company doesn't score particularly highly on the Joel Test :)

Comment: Yeah, even this new site, after I browsing 4 or 5 clicks popup comes out and saying that "site is unknown, click OK to contine, everything will be logged" or something like that, I was need to tunnel it through one of my proxy now. :(

Comment: I wish we could hire all the great programmers trapped behind companies like that. :(