# Support - Another thing from Meta

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, meta

We really need to have the support tag as a required tag.

Why? Well...

- [What is the syntax for specifying parameters?](https://stackapps.com/questions/87/what-is-the-syntax-for-specifying-parameters)
- [Is there a way of querying how much of the API limit has been used?](https://stackapps.com/questions/71/is-there-a-way-of-querying-how-much-of-the-api-limit-has-been-used)
- [Can I apply the API Key first and do the application later?](https://stackapps.com/questions/37/can-i-apply-the-api-key-first-and-do-the-application-later)
- [Is dev.meta.stackoverflow.com gone?](https://stackapps.com/questions/23/is-dev-meta-stackoverflow-com-gone)
- [Keep getting HTTP 406](https://stackapps.com/questions/59/keep-getting-http-406) (Possibly)

While many of these have the `discussion` tag on them, there are really more `support` related. Also, there will probably be a lot of support in the future about how to use the API, etc.

Answer (score 4):

I totally agree:

**Discussion:** dialog revolving around a topic

**Support:** a request for assistance or clarification

*discussion != support*